# Names of selected features in pruned RPART tree

Tags: r, tree, feature-selection, names, rpart

I would like to get the names of the features being used in my pruned RPART tree. I can read the names off the plotted pruned tree, but I prefer a vector of names.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a bit of effort, but you can get this. 
Since you do not provide any example, I will 
illustrate with some built-in data.

```
library(rpart)
libary(partykit)        ## for nicer plotting
IRP = rpart(Species ~ ., data=iris)
plot(as.party(IRP))
```

[image: iris tree]

One way to get at the variables used for the splits
is through the function `labels`.

```
labels(IRP)
[1] "root"               "Petal.Length< 2.45" "Petal.Length>=2.45"
[4] "Petal.Width< 1.75"  "Petal.Width>=1.75"
```

It is easy to ignore the first (root) node, but we need 
to clean up the text for the other splits. We can use `sub`
and a regular expression to get just the variable names.

```
VPat = paste0(".*(", paste(colnames(iris), collapse="|"), ").*")
sub(VPat,"\\1", labels(IRP)[-1])
[1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Petal.Width"
```

If you want, you can apply `unique` to this to just get each
variable name once.